# PHP code to require another script from four directory levels lower

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I am a newbie in php and I have a problem in getting another script to run in my code. The script I want to run are in the same folders but the one being included are in a folder four levels below.please help me. My directory tree is as shown below.

```
websystem\-
          |-Administrator\
          |-vehicle_details\vehicles\aston_martin\index.php
          |-explore-vehicle.php

require(".../websystems/explore-vehicle.php");
```

I have written my code above but it doesn't seem to run the script. asuming my home directory is aston_martin, I want to run the script `explore-vehicle.php` four levels below. My directory is `\websystems\vehicles_details\vehicles\aston_martin\index.php` and I want to run a script in `\websystems\explore-vehicle.php`.

Comment: In your example you have shown no less than three different spellings of `exploreVehicleDetails`. First and foremost make sure you're not simply misspelling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something along the lines of (assuming you're on the `index.php` page in `aston_martin`):

```
require("../../../explore-vehicle.php");
```

If you need to change a different directory, other than just the one you end up in, you could do that, e.g:

```
require("../../../../websystem/explore-vehicle.php");
```